# python oop classes, syntax error

Tags: python, syntax

The following is giving me a syntax error at (`def__init__(self, price, max_speed, total_miles_ridden, initial_miles = 0):`)

I'm also wondering if I can concatenate like this: `self.total_miles_ridden + 10`?
                                                                              ^:

```
class Bike(object):
    def__init__(self, price, max_speed, total_miles_ridden, initial_miles = 0):
        self.price = price
        self.max_speed = max_speed
        self.total_miles_ridden = total_miles_ridden
        self.initial_miles = initial_miles

    def displayinfo(self):
        print("The price is ", self.price)
        print("This bike's max speed is ", self.max_speed)
        print("The total miles is ", self.total_miles_ridden)

    def ride(self):
        print("Riding ", self.total_miles_ridden + 10) #add 10miles to total

    def reverse(self):
        print("Reversing " self.total_miles_ridden - 5) #minus 5 miles from total

bike1 = new Bike(200, '25mph')
print bike1
```

Comment: You are simply missing a space between `def` and `__init__`.

Comment: And yes, using `self.total_miles_ridden + 10` is a perfectly normal expression, but you are not altering the instance attribute, only producing a new value to be printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missing a space between def and **init**.